# Missing select keyword when inserting Xml data into table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I am trying to insert data from an XmlType variable into a table using Oracle's SQL Developer.

I am also very much a novice on Oracle. I am trying to pass XML data from a SQL Server database into Oracle using XML.

I have tried a number of solutions from Stack Overflow and other sites but nothing seems to work correctly.

The following is based on a solution that i did find on Stack Overflow. I am running this on Oracles SQL Developer:

```
with sample_data as (select xmltype(
'<People>
   <Person>
       <ID>PP11</ID>
   </Person>
   <Person>
       <ID>PP22</ID>
    </Person>
</People>') xml_data from dual) 

--INSERT INTO Person (ID)
select x.ID
from   sample_data sd
   cross join xmltable('/People/Person'
                       passing sd.xml_data
                       columns ID varchar2(20) path 'ID') x;
```

Notice that the Insert Into statement is commented out.

If I run this in SQL Developer as it is, I get:

```
ID                  
--------------------
PP11
PP22
```

If I include the Insert into statement I get:

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
with sample_data as (select xmltype(
'<People>
    <Person>
        <ID>PP11</ID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
       <ID>PP22</ID>
    </Person>
  </People>') xml_data from dual) 

INSERT INTO Person (ID)
select x.ID
from   sample_data sd
   cross join xmltable('/People/Person'
                       passing sd.xml_data
                       columns ID varchar2(20) path 'ID') x
Error at Command Line : 12 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong! I have done this with SQL Server and so would expect Oracle to be able to do it and so I must be missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct order of things are:

```
INSERT INTO Person (ID)
with sample_data as (select xmltype(
'<People>
    <Person>
        <ID>PP11</ID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
       <ID>PP22</ID>
    </Person>
  </People>') xml_data from dual) 
select x.ID
from   sample_data sd
   cross join xmltable('/People/Person'
                       passing sd.xml_data
                       columns ID varchar2(20) path 'ID') x
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your response. I have not been able to test it as SQL Developer is not working again! It was working and I made the mistake of closing it down and now it won't connect to Oracle XE now! That said it does look like I made a simple mistake and I am sure that once I get SQL Developer working again all will be OK. TVM!